# "Exceeds block gas limit" error when i try to send transaction via personal_sendTransaction

Tags: transactions, rinkeby

I wrote a program in Java, that create a request for a transaction and sends it through RPC API. My test network - Rinkeby.

This is request:

> curl -X POST --data '{"method":"personal_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"0x52f0bd94bddabe81111dfc283265933f64069f91","to":"0x31b98d14007bdee637298086988a0bbd31184523","gas":"0x40d4820000000000","gasPrice":"0x3e55798ee2308c3a","value":"0x3ff0000000000000"},"password"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}'  http://localhost:8545

where:

```
String value = "0x"+Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(1.0));//**0x3ff0000000000000**

String gasPrice = "0x"+Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(0.00000002));//**0x3e55798ee2308c3a**

String gas = "0x"+Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Double.parseDouble("21000")));//**0x40d4820000000000**
```

But I get the error:

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"exceeds block gas limit"}}.

Maybe I'm not correctly translating numbers into hex values?

Comment: The issue is you are using `doubleToLongBits`, from the java documentation:

> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "double format" bit layout.

But smart contracts in Ethereum only accept integers. In the case of values and gasPrice they are fixed point integers with 18 decimals.